# How to use Text-to-speech Festival java API?

Tags: java, text-to-speech, festival, freetts

I am trying to convert text to speech in java. I used `FreeTTS` but it doesnot provide recording feature or changing male voice to female voice using just `maven`.

I came across `festival.exe`. It is giving me all the features I require. But the issue is I am unable to find any festival related api that I can integrate with my java code.

Is there any **festival api** to use with java or any other text to speech conversion which will provide me required features(Also is open source)?

Comment: You can try openmary https://github.com/marytts/marytts

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanku!! I implemented it and it works fine for different voices. But I am still struggling with the audio generation. If you could help me?

Comment: You need to describe the problem first, not sure what are your troubles ;)

Comment: sure! I am trying to record a scenario using automation. So, there are various actions being performed which will be explained using test to speech. So what I basically want is an audio file with all the explanations and pauses in the same file while a particular action is being performed. Right now I am getting a number of audio files based on the number of times it speaks. I require a single audio file.

Comment: You can glue the files with custom code, it is not a TTS job to produce a proper timeline.